# Create lists in ListView from model field in django

Tags: python, django, listview, python-3.x, view

I would like to use ListView to generate lists of degrees by school and state. For example, I would want to use to the degree_awarded field in the Program model to make a list of "Schools in Pennsylvania Where You Can Get A Bachelor Degree."

Models

```
class State(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    state_slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state_slug

class City(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, default='')
    city_slug = models.SlugField()
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_slug

class School(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, default='')
    school_slug = models.SlugField()
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_slug

    def sorted_programs(self):
        return self.program_set.all().order_by('program_name')

class Program(models.Model):
    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    program_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, default='')
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, null=True)
    degree_awarded = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.program_slug
```

Views

```
class SchoolIndexView(ListView):
    model = State

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SchoolIndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['state_list'] = State.objects.all().order_by('state_name')
        return context

class ProgramInSchoolView(DetailView):
    model = School
    template = 'school_detail.html'

    def get_object(self):
        school_slug = School.objects.get(
            school_slug=self.kwargs.get('school_slug')
        )
        return school_slug

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProgramInSchoolView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['school'] = self.object
        context['program_list'] = self.object.program_set.all().order_by('program_name')

        return context

class ProgramView(DetailView):
    model = Program
    template = 'program_detail.html'

    def get_object(self):
        program_slug = Program.objects.get(
            program_slug=self.kwargs.get('program_slug')
        )
        return program_slug

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProgramView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['program'] = self.object
        context['program_classes'] = self.object.classes_set.all().order_by('class_number')

        return context

class DegreeView(ListView):
    model = Program
    template = 'degree_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DegreeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['state_for_degree'] = State.objects.get(state_slug=self.kwargs.get('state_slug'))
        context['city_for_degree'] = City.objects.get(city_name=self.kwargs.get('city_name'))
        context['school_for_degree'] = School.objects.get(school_slug=self.kwargs.get('school_slug'))
        context['degree_by_state'] = Program.objects.get(degree_awarded=self.kwargs.get('degree_awarded')).filter(school_slug=school_slug).filter(city_slug=city_slug).filter(state_slug=state_slug).order_by('city_name')

        return context
```

Urls

```
    url(r'^(?P<state_slug>[\w-]+)/$', CityInStateView.as_view(), name='state_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<state_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<school_slug>[\w-]+)/$', ProgramInSchoolView.as_view(), name='school_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<state_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<school_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<program_slug>[\w-]+)/$', ProgramView.as_view(), name='program_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<state_slug<[\w-]+)/(?P<program_slug>[\w-]+)/$', DegreeView.as_view(), name='degree_list'),
```

I cannot figure out how to write the view and url routing so that I can use the information I already have in the degree_awarded field of the Program model to generate a list.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Edit: I've added the relevant model(s) that I left out before. I wanted to be concise. I've also added in the last filter that I tried. It is still not producing the degree lists sorted by state.

Comment: First you need to get the right queryset. What part of "Schools in Pennsylvania Where You Can Get A Bachelor Degree." do you find difficult? Do you know how to get schools with state slug "PA"? Do you know how to get schools with batchelors degree programs? Note that you've missed out the `City` model (I guess it has a foreign key to `State`).

Comment: The city model isn't relevant. I edited it out. I know how to do all of the things that you've asked. However, I struggle with QuerySets. I don't really know to put it all together for the desired result.

Comment: I think the city model is relevant, how else are you going to get a list of schools in Pennsylvania? If you know how to write those queries, then add them to your question, and you'll be half way there.

Comment: I need the schools by state, not by city. I am able to use the queries in the views to query the schools by state. The hard part is knowing how to pull out the degree_awarded field from the Program model to query degrees by state. I don't know how to do that. I've tried filtering, but that doesn't work. Two days later, I'm here asking the question.

Comment: For the models you have shown, it's impossible to get a list schools for a particular state, because the school has no `state` field. If you've tried filtering, then show what you've tried. You asked to be pointed in the right direction, so I'm reluctant to write your code for you.

Comment: I understand. I don't want the code. I want to learn how to do it myself. I'll update soon.

Comment: Is `DegreeView` the view you are trying to write? Do you want to list the "**Schools** Pennsylvania Where You Can Get A Bachelor Degree", or the "**Programs** in Pennsylvania Where You Can Get A Bachelor Degree"?

Comment: Yes, I would like to write DegreeView. I want it to create the list from the degree_awarded field of the Program model.

Comment: Note that doing `Model.get(...).filter(...)` doesn't make sense. When you do `get()`, you are trying to retrieve a single instance. You can't filter any more after that.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up get() while filtering. I will test out your answer. Thanks again for time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need all that code in the `get_context_data` method. You should customize the list of objects to display in the [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method.

```
class DegreeView(ListView):
    model = Program
    template = 'degree_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(DegreeView, self).get_queryset()
        # batchelors degrees only
        queryset = queryset.filter(program_slug=self.kwargs['program_slug'])
        # filter by state
        queryset = queryset.filter(school__city__state__slug=self.kwargs['state_slug'])
        return queryset
```

See the docs on [lookups that span multiple relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) to explain the `school__city__state__slug` filter.

Then in your template, you can loop through the programs, for example:

```
{% for program in object_list %}
{{ program.degree_awarded %}
```